# Plane Curve Global Geometry / circumference of closed curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we know that for every point $c(t)$ on a closed, strictly convex curve $c:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, there is a unique point $c(t')$ such that $e_1(t)=-e_1(t')$. $c$ is said to have a constant width if $d(c(t), c(t') )=d$, a constant.

Prove: The circumference of a closed, strictly convex curve of contant width $=d$ is equal to $\pi d$.

Current Progress:

By reparametrization, we can let $\| c'(t) \| = 1$ for all $t\in I=[a,b]$.
Suppose $c'(t)=(\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t))$, then the curvature
$\kappa(t)=\theta'(t)$.

Since $c$ is strictly convex, w.l.o.g. $\kappa(t)>0$, and it is not hard to show that $\theta:I\rightarrow [0,2\pi]$ is diffeomorphism and increasing. Thus its inverse function $t(\theta)$ exists.

Let $e_1(\theta)=c'(t(\theta))$, write $\kappa(\theta)$ for $\kappa(t(\theta))$ when there is no confusion.

Let $f(\theta)=c(t(\theta + \pi)) - c(t(\theta))=\int_\theta^{\theta+\pi} e_1(\theta)/\kappa (\theta)d\theta\equiv d$.

$\frac d{d\theta}\|f(\theta)\|=\frac {[e_1(\theta+\pi)/\kappa(\theta+\pi) - e_1(\theta)/\kappa(\theta)]\cdot f(\theta)}{\|f(\theta)\|} = 0$.

But by our construction of $\theta$, $e_1(\theta + \pi)=-e_1(\theta)$,

Therefore, $\frac {[1/\kappa(\theta+\pi) /+ 1/\kappa(\theta)] e_1(\theta)\cdot f(\theta)}{\|f(\theta)\|}=0$ ,

thus $e_1(\theta)\cdot f(\theta)=e_1(\theta)\cdot (c(t(\theta + \pi)) - c(t(\theta)))=0$.

Up to now I manage to show that: if you draw a line through the points whose tangent vectors are in opposite directions, this line is perpendicular to the tangent vectors.

Now keep differentiating,

$\frac d{d\theta} e_1(\theta)\cdot (c(t(\theta + \pi)) - c(t(\theta)))$

$=Je_1(\theta) \cdot (c(t(\theta + \pi)) - c(t(\theta))) - e_1(\theta) \cdot e_1(\theta) [1/\kappa(\theta+\pi) + 1/\kappa(\theta)]=0$,

where $J=[\begin{array}{} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}]$ is the rotation matrix of 90 degrees counter-clockwisely.

But the first term is just the measure of the diameter, which is $d$!

Therefore, we get $1/\kappa(\theta+\pi) + 1/\kappa(\theta)=d$ for arbitary $\theta$.

By the inverse function theorem, the circumference of $c$ is $b-a=\int_0^{2\pi}1/\kappa(\theta)d\theta=\int_0^{\pi}(1/\kappa(\theta)+1/\kappa(\theta + \pi))d\theta=\pi d$.

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: Interesting... By the way is there other curves than circles satisfying such a property?

Comment: From this definition, the diameter is twice the distance of any point to the origin, and is a constant !

Comment: @Can you precise what $e_1(t)$ is? The tangent vector at $c(t)$ I imagine?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, the unit tangent vector of $c$ in the description, although in the current progress there is another definition, which shadows the above one.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net See Figure 2.5 on p. 19 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks Ted for the heads up! Indeed always take with intuitions... Your course makes me want to look again at 3D curves and surfaces differentials geometry that I haven’t touch seriously for  almost 25 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: If $\alpha(s)$ is an arclength parametrization of $c$, let $\beta(s)$ be a parametrization of the "opposite" curve. What is $\|\beta'(s)\|$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have got the answer :)

Comment: Great! If you have no further issues, you should accept the answer. :)